# Delete data in multiple tables laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have this problem, I want to delete some data in multiple tables (not using foreign keys), so I did make the query and laravel throw a SQL error, which has the query I made. So I copied and pasted the same query and executed it in MySql and it works. I don't know what is the problem. Here is the code:

```
$deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE user_id= " . $user->user_id . ";";        
$deleteQuery .= "DELETE FROM settings WHERE user_id= " . $user->user_id . ";";
$deleteQuery .= "DELETE FROM pictures WHERE user_id= " . $user->user_id . ";";

DB::delete($deleteQuery);
```

I also have tried with:

```
DB::delete($deleteQuery);
```

But it doesn't works.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't think DB::delete() supports multiple statements.  What's the point of grouping them together anyways?

Comment: The idea is to reduce the conections to database (correct me if I'm wrong). I could delete all data via Eloquent, but if I have like 5 0 6 tables I would like to reduce that conections to improve the speed.

Comment: It's not going to launch a new connection for every query..  Even so, how often are you deleting?  Seems like you're overconcerned about optimizing.

Comment: @Devon Interesting... So you say that the conection are closed when the Request Cycle is finished?

Answer (score 4):

You are putting multiple delete statements in one place. The `DB::delete()` function does not support that.

You can send the database multiple delete queries like so

```
DB::table("posts")->where("user_id", $userID)->delete();
DB::table("settings")->where("user_id", $userID)->delete();
DB::table("pictures")->where("user_id", $userID)->delete();
```

Or if you really want to do it in one go you could do something like this:

```
DB::RAW("DELETE FROM posts WHERE user_id= ?; 
DELETE FROM settings WHERE user_id= ?; 
DELETE FROM pictures WHERE user_id= ?, 
array($userID, $userID, $userID));
```

Take a look at the query builder documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#deletes

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
**DB::statement($deleteQuery);**
```

*In Laravel, `DB::statement()` runs the sql query.*

*For Ex:*

> $query = "UPDATE `table_name` SET `field` = value";
>   DB::statement($query);

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.